# Movie where a guy's stomach gets blown out

Tags: story-identification

This is the only scene I remember which I believe was from a sci-fi movie set in the future.  A group of people, being held prisoners, try to escape. I think they're wearing orange and one of them sits on a chair and presses buttons (think he was wearing glasses). Afterwards, his stomach gets blown out and before he dies, he presses another button.

- I watched this in the early-mid nineties so the movie was probably made around then
- Watched in the UK but pretty sure the movie was American (in English)
- Not sure who was in it, maybe Kevin Costner (could it be The Postman?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given the orange he's wearing and the stomach device/bomb, I suggest "[Fortress](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106950/)" (1992), starring Christopher Lambert.

> In a future, private underground prison/Fortress, the inmates are computer controlled with CCTV, dream readers and devices that can cause pain or death. John and his illegally pregnant wife are inside but want to escape before birth.

### Trailer

Comment: The embedded video says: "This video contains content from Miramax, who has blocked it in your country on copyright grounds." I'm in the US.

Comment: @DCShannon - I've seen the movie. You should probably be thanking Miramax :D

Comment: Your video link has gone dead.